# Identify multiple user in Speech to Text (React Native)

Tags: react-native

How can I identify multiple users in Speech to Text conversion in React Native?
I have using React Native Voice library but it only transcribe user voice into text but unable to identify different user but my need is to identify Speaker 1, Speaker 2 and so on.